# Rails / ActiveStorage File Processing – only on-the-fly or also on upload? If so, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm planning a RoR project that involves the upload and compression of videos. Normally I'd go with Shrine for handling file attachments and handle video compression with *ffmpeg* in a background job after the upload.

Now that `ActiveStorage` is built-in Rails 5.2, I'd like to opt for that, but I'm not sure if it could handle video (w/ compression) well. So far, I only found documentation on processing images (with MiniMagick) or creating video-/pdf-previews (with ffmpeg or mutools) which all seem to happen on-the-fly.

As the compression of videos is time-intense I'd say that it should happen directly after the upload to be ready for requests. **Is there on option the process files after upload, using ActiveStorage, or only on-the-fly**?

If not, why or rather is it recommended to handle all file processing **on-the-fly**?

Thanks

Comment: I am also interested in a solution of the problem. Did you solve it in the meantime?

Comment: No, i did not find a solution for this case yet and not documentation was mentioning a different solution so far. I continued using `Shrine` which is imo the best and most versatile uploading solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See how I solved it in my post below.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution for converting a video to MP4 after it´s uploaded. Maybe not the cleanest one but it works. I use Delayed::Job to handle the call asynchronously.

```
def process_video!
  if video.attached? && video.blob.content_type != 'video/mp4'

    orig_video_tmpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{video.blob.key}_#{video.blob.filename.to_s}"
    mp4_video_tmpfile = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{video.blob.key}_#{video.blob.filename.base}.mp4"
    File.open(orig_video_tmpfile, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(video.download)
    end

    system('ffmpeg', '-i', orig_video_tmpfile, mp4_video_tmpfile)

    self.video.attach(
      io: File.open(mp4_video_tmpfile),
      filename: "#{video.blob.filename.base}.mp4",
      content_type: 'video/mp4'
    )

    File.delete(orig_video_tmpfile)
    File.delete(mp4_video_tmpfile)
  end
end
handle_asynchronously :process_video!
after_commit :process_video!
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Regarding the use of `ffmpeg`, there is a helpful library called [streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg) to use with Rails and in [here i made use of it to convert a video](https://github.com/paulbernhard/pshr/blob/development/app/uploaders/pshr/processors/video.rb) file for various versions for Shrine, but it should work with anything.